# Fancybox full width

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox, vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm new to coding and I'm trying to have every fancybox ONLY in my [homepage](http://www.watersidedirectors.com/) full width and responsive ([eg](http://www.anonymouscontent.com/)) but non of these options have done the job (fitToView, autoSize or aspectRatio).

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery( "#site-logo" ).click(function( e ) {
    alert( "As you can see, the link no longer took you to jquery.com" );
    jQuery.scrollTo( 0 , 1000, { easing:'easeInOutExpo' });
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    helpers : {
        media: true 
        },
        width: 1600,
        height: 870,
        aspectRatio: true,
        scrolling: no,
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you checked http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful No. 13?

Comment: @JFK Yes, I've looked also into the guide looking for a solution. Also #13 still not workin=(

Comment: @JFK Digging in stackover I found this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28079791/change-vimeo-youtube-default-size-in-wordpress).
Tried to add this code into function.php and took off css/jquery fancybox but still no changes.

Comment: @JFK What if I want the fancybox open in full screen? fitToView isn't working..

Answer (score 6):

Try adding an autoSize false, removing the aspectRatio and changing the width to "100%":

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery( "#site-logo" ).click(function( e ) {
    alert( "As you can see, the link no longer took you to jquery.com" );
    jQuery.scrollTo( 0 , 1000, { easing:'easeInOutExpo' });
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        helpers : {
            media: true 
        },
        width: "100%",
        height: 870,
        autoSize: false,
        scrolling: false
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Digging in stackover I found this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28079791/change-vimeo-youtube-default-size-in-wordpress).
Tried to add this code into function.php and took off css/jquery fancybox but still no changes.

Comment: Strange. Let's start from the beggining, you need to use fancybox only?

Comment: Actually nope, I want for each slide the video to pop up full width & responsive (or something like 1300x731), like in the [eg]. (http://www.anonymouscontent.com/).
Since I didn't install fancybox plugin, the fancybox must be inside this theme, that's why I used it. I'm open to any option if there's another way to achieve the eg.

Comment: Hmm got it. And what if you try to change your css, in `.fancybox-wrap, .fancybox-wrap .fancybox-skin{width: 100% !important; height: 100% !important; margin: 0px; text-align: center}`?

Comment: Matter of the fact this was My first solution but as you can see [now](http://www.watersidedirectors.com) the skin is way too big (my lap is 1680 x 1050) and the video  is small. Then I've tried to add also `.fancybox-wrap, .fancybox-inner{width: 100% !important; height: 100% !important; margin: 0px; text-align: center}` and the video is like the wrap, kinda outta space=)

Comment: And if you set the `fitToView` to true?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69450/discussion-on-answer-by-dimas-pante-fancybox-full-width).

Comment: Nothing changed. I've also tried to apply that code only on home page, in order to avoid bugs on [director's page](http://www.watersidedirectors.com/directors/) `.home .fancybox-wrap, .fancybox-wrap .fancybox-skin {width: 100% !important; height: 100% !important; margin: 0px; text-align: center;}`

Comment: @bluefeet Thank you bluefeet, I was not able to do it due to my low rep points=)

Comment: @joemimmo You should be able to now because I moved your conversation.

Comment: So, have you come to a solution? I have the same problem. Fancybox on my web site only uses about 70% of the screen width... I use viewport definition which allows zooming.

Answer (score 1):

For  anyone else looking in future searches I had the same problem where I needed the image (pop up) to be full width, even if the image has overflow height so I wanted it to be scrollable.  Anyways I hope this helps someone in the future.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        autoSize : true,
        scrolling : 'auto',
        fitToView : false,
        width : 'auto',
        maxWidth : '100%',
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: As Rev slider had a huge update I have no chance to test it, anyone else succeeded?
http://www.wdirectors.com/

Answer (score 0):

In my side nothing solution worked. so i posted my solution that working my side.
this code should be place on that page where your **pop blade** code written.

```
.fancybox-content {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
```