# Change Vimeo/Youtube default size in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, youtube, vimeo

How to change Vimeo/Youtube embed sizes?

Currently the default embed is very small 300x150, i need 540px minimum :(

Using snippet to filter in functions.php, the code no works.

```
function rezzz_embed_defaults($defaults) {
    $defaults['width'] = 350;
    $defaults['height'] = 200;

    return $defaults;
}

add_filter('embed_defaults','rezzz_embed_defaults');
```

Please see screenshot -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/gweev.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see your code carefully. I have used your code but changed width and height.

```
function rezzz_embed_defaults($defaults) {
    $defaults['width'] = 540;
    $defaults['height'] = 304;

    return $defaults;
}

add_filter('embed_defaults','rezzz_embed_defaults');
```

You need to provide width and height in proper ratio to use video from youtube, vimeo and other source.

You can see working demo of above code [here](http://manesh.com.np/embed-demo/)

Comment: Currently i'm using the embed in a Lightbox (Lightbox plus colorbox), inserting code via admin in a post.

Comment: It does not make any difference whether you are using it in lightbox or post/page. Size of video will be what you provide in above function.

Comment: Your code works perfectly, the problem was Lightbox Plus Colorbox, i'm not remember to setup width and height for lightbox.